# HTML5 video playback is choppy and corrupted in Firefox

Tags: firefox, video

I am only experiencing this issue with Firefox. Other browsers work fine. Here are my specs:

- Firefox 28.0
- Windows 7 Ultimate, 64-bit
- Intel HD Graphics (driver up-to-date)

When I view an HTML5 video (e.g. `<video>`), the playback is incredibly choppy and the video has some corruption/artifacts near the top of the frame.

Flash videos run fine in Firefox.

I've used a screen recorded to capture this issue. Here is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=-XAkLHqk3tc

> Note: I used the video on Vimeo.com as an example. Vimeo is not the only website serving HTML5 video that is causing problems in my Firefox browser.

One the left is Firefox and on the right is Google Chrome. Google Chrome does not have any issues playing the video.

Any ideas on what is wrong or how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 12):

This issue was resolved by disabling Hardware Acceleration.

1. Go to **Firefox Menu > Options > Options > Advanced**
2. Uncheck **Use hardware acceleration when available**
3. Click **OK**

   [image: screenshot]
4. Restart Firefox

Comment: I had the same issue and your advice helped. I think my HD 4000 GPU was bottlenecking my i7 CPU.

Answer (score -1):

In the add ons for Firefox download the HTML5 player in the second box titled up and coming extensions, that solved the problem for youtube, but didn't Vimeo, I've not found a solution for the Vimeo problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is the exact add-on required?